# automatically log in with converse.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, converse.js

I'm trying to modify the Converse.js client to automatically bind an anonymous user to a moderator without login. If the client pops up, the user shouldn't get a login prompt but automatically connect to a logged in moderator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see here on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In your case, some code to reproduce your problem would really help us help you.

Comment: Also, if you have two questions - please create two questions. Discussing two questions at the same time doesn't work. So I suggest that you remove the last paragraph and put it up as a new question, with further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [auto_login](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#auto-login) configuration setting, possibly together with the [credentials_url](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#credentials-url) setting, so that the JID and password of the moderator are fetched automatically by converse.js.

For example, you'll then initialize converse.js like this:

```
converse.initialize({
    'allow_logout': false,
    'auto_login': 'true',
    'auto_reconnect': true,
    'bosh_service_url': 'https://bosh.example.org',
    'credentials_url': 'https://example.org/credentials'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case I want to do this with SASL anonymous or i need a plugin on client site which generate a jid, which registers itself on log-in to the server and unregister after log-out. 

I'm not professional familiar with any programming language and maybe anybody else has doing this before. Otherwise I have to study the development guide from Converse.js.

Comment: I don't think you can log in with SASL anonymous and then be logged in as a moderator. At least not with the general XMPP servers, although it might be possible if you customize your XMPP server. That said, I think that's a server issue, and not related to the client (e.g. converse.js).

Comment: The Moderator is already logged in. He is like an Agent and wait for a customer for example. On ejabberd i've created some virtual hosts and for each hosts also shared roster groups. It works, that the moderator immediately can see if a user logging onto his virtual host. But in my case i want to directly connect the anonymous user to the already logged in moderator and i don't know if I can do this on server side.

Comment: What do you mean with "directly connect"?

Comment: HI :) There is only one admin/moderator/operator "Bender" (Bender@example.test1.com) on the virtual host "example.test1.com". If a anonymous user logs into the domain (or vh) "example.test1.com", he should be connected directly to "Bender" like any other anonymous user who logs into this domain.

Comment: What do you mean with "connected directly to" ? Do you mean a chat window should open up, so that the user can chat with Bender?

Comment: exactly. like a support chat. the user connect to Bender and get an announcement. I've tried that with a muc but in a muc every one else can see each other and what the others write.